# Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools configuration settings

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-extensions

I'm trying to figure out where the Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools settings are stored. I recently moved to a new instance of visual studio and I've lost all of my Power Tools regex tab coloring settings. They are clearly not part of the normal VS2010 settings file, as I exported and imported this already. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's just stored in the registry under

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0
```

It seems the regexes are under

```
...\DialogPage\Microsoft.DocWellBehavior.Options.ColorCodingOptions
```

Comment: You are absolutely awesome for finding this! I searched all over the place! Thank you so much!

Comment: For VS2012, they reside under `...\11.0\DialogPage\Microsoft.CustomDocWell.Options\Colors`

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments -- nobody will see them. Ask a new question instead.