# Is it possible to import Visual Studio Power Tools settings?

Tags: import, registry, registrykey, visual-studio-power-tools

Recently I've upgraded from VS2013 to VS2015. I've imported my settings file from 13 to 15. Now I would like to import my settings for the extension 'Visual Studio Power Tools'. Specifically the document well regex settings. I use this to color my tabs differently in each of my three environments, for each of the file types. I was able to find where these settings are stored thanks to this question:

[Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools configuration settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087469/visual-studio-productivity-power-tools-configuration-settings)

I've located these settings, but now my question is: how do I import them into VS2015? I'm not very experienced messing with the registry and don't want to muck something up. So far I was able to export the specific reg settings for my VS2013 colors. I also found the location of the color settings folder (in the registry) for vs2015. Is it possible to somehow take that .reg file I exported and import it into the settings for vs2015? Thanks for any help. It's greatly appreciated!

Edit: So it's been a week or so and I've gotten no responses to the question :(
I suppose another way to ask this would be: "is there a way to import registry settings?"

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2015 those settings are stored under a registry key:

```
 HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\DialogPage
```

Assuming that the plugin didn't change the way its color settings are stored, it should be enough to edit the **.reg** file that you exported from Visual Studio 2013 in a chosen text editor (`notepad.exe` will do) and replace all ocurrences of `\12.0\` (which is version number of VS2013) with `\14.0\` (which is version number of VS2015).

Then you may open the **.reg** file to import settings.

By the way, if you would like to include registry settings like this in your backup plan, you might easily export registry keys from a command line with something like:

```
 regedit /e d:\VSPowerToolsColorSettingsBackup.reg "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\DialogPage"
```